# I am deploying my Laravel project on live server with FileZilla and infinity free and I got this problem

Tags: php, composer-php

Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0".

Note: I am currently using the latest PHP Version which is 8.1.6

Comment: It depends. There's a CLI and a server version. Run phpinfo() from your webscript and CLI.

Comment: Do you have cPanel?

Comment: yes I have Cpanel

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags. Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cPanel, Under the `SOFTWARE` tab:

1. go to `MultiPHP Manager`, select the domain, then in the dropdown where you have PHP versions, select `PHP 8.1 (ea-php81)` and click on `Apply`
2. go to `Select PHP Version`. You would see a drop down for `current php version`. Click the dropdown and select `8.1` and click `set as current`(after you must have selected the domain).

Doing these above two things should clear the error your composer gives.

Comment: unfortunately I dont have 'MultiPHP Manager'

Comment: Have you done the second option?

Comment: it was also not there

Comment: Are you sure you have cPanel?

Comment: does this mean i have to do an upgrade on my infinityfree or something?

Comment: yes im sure i have cpanel

Comment: ive also seen this kind of solution on youtube but i couldnt do them cause i dont have the said features/categories